# jboss integration with LDAP

Tags: java, jboss, ldap

I have an application which currently uses JDBC to authenticate the users that login to the application. But now I want that it should be able to use LDAP to login into my application. My boss wants me to integrate LDAP with JBOSS in order to achieve it. I am new to LDAP and have no idea on what needs to be done. Can anybody suggest something ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom **security domain** in JBoss' standalone.xml.
In this domain you can configure your LDAP settings. [See this for some details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015462/ldap-authentication-with-jboss-7)
The LDAP settings depend on the LDAP you are using, so there are no general working settings.

**Here would be an example:**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.0">
<security-domains>
    <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
        <authentication>
            <login-module code="Disabled" flag="required"/>
        </authentication>
    </security-domain>
    <security-domain name="test_ldap_security_domain">
        <authentication>
            <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
                <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
                <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://10.10.10.10:389"/>
                <module-option name="bindDN" value="cn=abc,cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com"/>
                <module-option name="bindCredential" value="Test@123"/>
                <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com"/>
                <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(userPrincipalName={0})"/>
                <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com"/>
                <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(userPrincipalName={0})"/>
                <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
                <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
                <module-option name="Context.REFERRAL" value="follow"/>
                <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
                <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
                <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="true"/>
            </login-module>
            <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.RoleMappingLoginModule" flag="optional">
                <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="/home/userone/jboss-as-7.0.1.Final/standalone/configuration/test-roles.properties"/>
                <module-option name="replaceRole" value="false"/>
            </login-module>
        </authentication>
    </security-domain>
</security-domains>
</subsystem>
```

Depending on the type of application, you need some config in your app to make the app use this domain.

If you have a web application (.war) you need a jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/test_ldap_security_domain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

You can now use standard JavaEE authentication/authorization mechanisms.E.g. in the web.xml.