# Issue authenticating user on JBoss 7 against LDAP

Tags: authentication, ldap, jboss7.x

I am trying setup authentication on an application on JBoss 7 against a LDAP Server. Below is the link I have followed for the configuration

[LDAP authentication with JBoss 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015462/ldap-authentication-with-jboss-7/15908773#15908773)

The LDAP login module performs three queries against the LDAP server to log in a user, as follows:

As per JBoss in Action, there are 3 steps how JBoss LDAP Login Module works:
- The first query looks up the user object using only the login id. This search is similar to the first ldapsearch query that we showed you earlier.
- A second query is a login attempt using the user’s login id and the password.
- The last query obtains the group objects.
The password is used, but you don’t have to reference it in the login module. Now let’s take a look at another login module that helps simplify development and testing.

Looking in the LDAP Server logs it looks like my setup is only doing the first step but not the 2nd. So the login fails with a password error :

10:47:11,448 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (http-/127.0.0.1:9080-1) PBOX000283: Bad password for username testuser1
10:47:11,450 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/127.0.0.1:9080-1) PBOX000244: Begin abort method
10:47:11,450 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (http-/127.0.0.1:9080-1) PBOX000206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX000070: Password invalid/Password required
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:286) [picketbox-4.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.1.1.Final-redhat-1]

Here is the configuration from my standalone.xml:

```
            <security-domain name="LDAPAuth" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
                        <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://localhost:389"/>
                        <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
                        <module-option name="bindDN" value="cn=admin"/>
                        <module-option name="bindCredential" value="********"/>
                        <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="ou=Internal,cn=Users,dc=company,dc=local"/>
                        <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(cn={0})"/>
                        <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(uniqumember={1})"/>
                        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
                        <module-option name="Context.REFERRAL" value="follow"/>
                        <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="roleRecursion" value="0"/>
                        <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        <module-option name="Context.REFERRAL" value="follow"/>
                        <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

Comment: Often, the loginname in Microsoft Active Directory is NOT the same as the cn. Might try changing CN={0} to samAccountName={0}.

Comment: We have tested against 2 LDAP implementations - OpenLDAP & Oracle Internet Directory. Independently we are able to bind the CN from the command line.

Comment: Can you provide the command you are using?

Comment: We are just trying to use basic authentication. Some more progress after I have added one more module option: <module-option name="distinguishedNameAttribute" value="distinguishedname"/>, I can see LDAP have send a success to the UserBind request, so LDAP is authenticating the user but JBoss still throws the same error as before.

Comment: Manage to get this working with Oracle Internet Directory. Final module option which helped to work - <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=Internal,cn=Groups,dc=company,dc=local"/>